# Maps component is not working in Jasper 6.2.0

Tags: jasper-reports

We need a help to execute the maps in jasper report
    We have used below command which is working fine in 6.2.0 (10/6/2018).
    Now it is stop to display map and getting error. Hence we added map.key to resolve and also experimented with latest map component, but not able get map as previously.
Could you please help us to resolve this issue.
Thank you

#### Map key data

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.components.map.key" value="AIzaSy**********5w"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.components.map.version" value="3"/>
```

#### map component added in summary

```
<componentElement>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="572" height="680" uuid="d66b99c0-0651-47f0-954f-90fc23b4a344">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{row_num}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <c:map xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" evaluationTime="Band" mapType="hybrid">
                <c:latitudeExpression><![CDATA[Float.parseFloat($F{center_lat})]]></c:latitudeExpression>
                <c:longitudeExpression><![CDATA[Float.parseFloat($F{center_lng})]]></c:longitudeExpression>
                <c:zoomExpression><![CDATA[Integer.parseInt($P{ZOOM})]]></c:zoomExpression>
                <c:markerData>
                    <dataset/>
                    <c:item>
                        <c:itemProperty name="latitude">
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[Float.parseFloat($F{latitude})]]></valueExpression>
                        </c:itemProperty>
                        <c:itemProperty name="longitude">
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[Float.parseFloat($F{longitude})]]></valueExpression>
                        </c:itemProperty>
                        <c:itemProperty name="label">
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{row_num}]]></valueExpression>
                        </c:itemProperty>
                    </c:item>
                </c:markerData>
            </c:map>
        </componentElement>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: I have [edit]ed the node and indented the XML so it renders properly. This helps people spot errors

Comment: [Electem] Added a new map component(from jaspersoft_studio(6.6.0) tool) on click palette >> Map and generated a report with static key, latitude and longitude coordinates